# How to draw a poker card for my blackjack game?

Tags: python-2.7

```
def box_lines(lines, width):
    topBottomRow = "┌" + "-" * width + "┐"
    # bottomRow = "└" + "-" * length + "┘"
    middle = "\n".join("|" + x.ljust(width) + "|" for x in lines)
    return "{0}\n{1}\n{0}".format(topBottomRow, middle)

def split_line(line, width):
    return [line[i:i + width] for i in range(0, len(line), width)]

def split_msg(msg, width):
    lines = msg.split("\n")
    split_lines = [split_line(line, width) for line in lines]
    return [item for sublist in split_lines for item in sublist]

def border_msg(msg, width):
    return(box_lines(split_msg(msg, width), width))

print(border_msg("""♣


                                       ♣""", 20))
```

This is what I keep getting....

```
┌--------------------┐
|♣                   |
|                    |
|                   ♣|
┌--------------------┐
```

I don't know how fix it. I'm trying to draw a card for my oop blackjack game. The card needs to be longer and the bottom symbols I commented out in the code need to be used to make a full rectangle.

Comment: What should the card look like?

Comment: I just want a simple playing card.

Comment: Is the problem that you aren't using the bottom row?  That's why those little corners are flipped - you are using the top row for the bottom as well.

Comment: @dasnick yes, I tried to use the flipped symbols so that it would be a complete rectangle but it made a small rectangle and wasn't formatting it correctly. Im also unsure on how to make it longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something that you'd like to achieve?

```py
def border_msg(color, height, width):
    card_content_width = width - 2
    lines = ['┌' + '-' * card_content_width + '┐']
    lines.append('|' + color + ' ' * (card_content_width - 1) + '|')
    lines.extend(['|' + ' ' * card_content_width + '|' for i in range(height - 4)])
    lines.append('|' + ' ' * (card_content_width - 1) + color + '|')
    lines.append('└' + '-' * card_content_width + '┘')
    return '\n'.join(lines)

print(border_msg("♣", 10, 20))
```

Above code gives you such card:

```
┌------------------┐
|♣                 |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                 ♣|
└------------------┘
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed it to look like! Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.